# I have muliple arrays of single object with multiple values and i want to get these values and display them

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native, javascript-objects

I,m having an issue in getting object with multiple arrays. How can i get multiple array of single object.

[image]

Comment: Donot post image of code, instead paste the relavent code in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `console.table()` to your table. You can declare a variable named as `cardDatas`. Then you can use `console.table(cardDatas)`. Please consider to share the code by enclosing the full code in ``? Then I can provide the output for you.

Answer (score 0):

If the data is consistent, you can create a new array, for loop throw your initial array and push your elements.

Something like this.

```js
const data = [
    {
        cardData: [
            {
                title: "a",
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        cardData: [
            {
                title: "b",
            },
        ],
    },
];

let cardData = [];

for (const elm of data) {
  cardData.push(elm.cardData[0]);
}

console.log(`cardData`, cardData);
```

Comment: Thank you btw I have solved that